# Does $2^{k+1} = 2^k * 2^1$?

Tags: exponentiation

I'm not sure how to deal with an exponent like this.  Can I simplify it into terms that are easier to work with?

I know that $2^3 · 2^4 = 2^{3+4} = 128$, but I don't know about $2^{k + 1}$

Comment: Yes, this law of exponents works with $k+1$ just as it does with $3+4$.  $$ 2^{k+1} = 2^k \cdot 2^1 = 2^k \cdot 2 $$  What was it you didn't think you knew?

Comment: Yes.  $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$.

Comment: I've learned that sometimes it's not as simple as I think it is : ) But thanks for confirming.

Comment: When you see $k$ in such a context, you can assume that $k$ is integer, *most of the time*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $2^{k+1} ≡ 2·2^{k}$

And that is roughly as simplified as $2^{k+1}$ can get.

Of course you can rewrite it in many different ways, but without the context of a problem it is hard to know which one is best.

For instance, you can rewrite it as $e^{x·\ln{2}}$.